# Showing rows with the same value in one row on Xslt

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

There is a table, table has 5 rows. Some rows has same `<Name>`.

**I want to show same-named rows in one row with adding `<Quantity>` if `<UnitPrice>` is same too.**

I have xml and xslt and i see that:

```
ID  Name    UnitPrice   Quantity 
1   A       5           30 
2   A       5           40 
3   A       6           50 
4   C       6           25 
5   V       10          15
```

I want to see

```
1   A   10  70 
3   A   6   50 
4   C   6   25 
5   V   10  15
```

I have that xml:

```html
<Items>
    <Item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <UnitPrice>5</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>30</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <UnitPrice>5</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>40</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <UnitPrice>6</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>50</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <UnitPrice>6</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>25</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <Name>V</Name>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>15</Quantity>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

and i made an xslt like that :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>      
      <body>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width ="50">ID</td>
              <td width ="50">Name</td>
              <td width ="50">UnitPrice</td>
              <td width ="50">Quantity</td>           
            </tr>        
            <xsl:for-each select = "//Items/Item" >
              <xsl:apply-templates select = "." />
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//Items/Item">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="./ID"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="./Name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="./UnitPrice"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="./Quantity"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That is a grouping problem, you want to use `<xsl:for-each-group select="/Items/Item" group-by="ID, UnitPrice" composite="yes">` in XSLT 3 or `<xsl:for-each-group select="/Items/Item" group-by="concat(ID, '|', UnitPrice)">` in XSLT 2.

Comment: i can not use for-each-group 
i am getting this error while i am compiling
The element 'template in namespace'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' has invalid child element 'for-each-group' in namespace'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'.

Comment: The don't post snippets having `version="2.0"` or better download and install an XSLT 2 processor like Saxon 9, then you can use `for-each-group`.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use any jar for processing xslt. Because our system is not compatible with java. Completely we are using c# and using System.Xml System.Xml.Xsl.
Even so thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, you can use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

You want to group by `Name` and `UnitPrice` so you need to create a composite key (similar to the `group-by` in the other answer).

However, it doesn't make sense to sum the `UnitPrice` so I'm going to assume that the `10` in:

```
1 A 10 70
```

in your desired output is a typo. If this is an incorrect assumption, the `UnitPrice` can also be summed similar to the way `Quantity` is summed:

```
sum(key('items',concat(Name,'|',UnitPrice))/UnitPrice)
```

Full example...

**XML**

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <UnitPrice>5</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>30</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <UnitPrice>5</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>40</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <UnitPrice>6</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>50</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <UnitPrice>6</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>25</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <Name>V</Name>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>15</Quantity>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="items" match="Item" use="concat(Name, '|', UnitPrice)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="50">ID</td>
              <td width="50">Name</td>
              <td width="50">UnitPrice</td>
              <td width="50">Quantity</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="Items/Item[count(.|key('items',concat(Name,'|',UnitPrice))[1])=1]"/>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="UnitPrice"/></td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of 
        select="sum(key('items',concat(Name,'|',UnitPrice))/Quantity)"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (Click "Run Code Snippet" to see formatted HTML.)

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td width="50">ID</td>
               <td width="50">Name</td>
               <td width="50">UnitPrice</td>
               <td width="50">Quantity</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>A</td>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>70</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>A</td>
               <td>6</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>C</td>
               <td>6</td>
               <td>25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>V</td>
               <td>10</td>
               <td>15</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had simplified my problem to ask. This answer worked on that i asked.
I slogged on adapting this solution to my main problem. Because i didnt understand exactly how it works. Especially this :
 <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="Items/Item[count(.|key('items',concat(Name,'|',UnitPrice))[1])=1]"/>
I am working for 5-6 months with xslt but i dont understand exactly still. But it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below XSLT to group the similar elements and then access the group to get the required output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50">ID</td>
                            <td width="50">Name</td>
                            <td width="50">UnitPrice</td>
                            <td width="50">Quantity</td>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="//Items/Item" group-by="concat(Name,'|',UnitPrice)">
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="ID" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/UnitPrice)" /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Quantity)" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thx for swift reply but i am getting this error 
what am i doing wrong 
The element 'template in namespace'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' has invalid child element 'for-each-group' in namespace'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'. List of possible elements expected: 'param, apply-templates, call-template, apply-imports, for-each, value-of, copy-of, number, choose, if, text, copy, variable, message, fallback, processing-instruction, comment, element, attribute in namespace'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' as well as any element in namespace ##other.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Thanks for the suggestion (still in the learning phase of XSLT 2.0). I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @kordiseps - Can you check the XSLT 2.0 processor being used? I have tested using `saxon9he`.

Comment: I am using c# and my code is in : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163431.aspx

Comment: In addition w3scoolls try it editor didn't run this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog